# Is there a reference documentation for the Kubectl YAML data formats?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm trying to find all the allowed formats used when specifying quotas, but all I can find are examples that may not cover all the cases. For instance

- CPU limits are expressed in milliCPU ("200m") but it seems plain integer are also acceptable and maybe even decimal numbers.
- Storage size examples are in "Gi" but there could be other units?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Resource units in Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#resource-units-in-kubernetes) section of the doc describes the meaning and the allowed values for the CPU and memory resources.

To quote:

**Meaning of CPU:**

> Limits and requests for CPU resources are measured in
> cpu units. One cpu, in Kubernetes, is equivalent to 1 vCPU/Core for
> cloud providers and 1 hyperthread on bare-metal Intel processors.

**Allowed values:**

> Fractional requests are allowed. A Container with
> spec.containers[].resources.requests.cpu of 0.5 is guaranteed half as
> much CPU as one that asks for 1 CPU. The expression 0.1 is equivalent
> to the expression 100m, which can be read as "one hundred millicpu".
> Some people say "one hundred millicores", and this is understood to
> mean the same thing. A request with a decimal point, like 0.1, is
> converted to 100m by the API, and precision finer than 1m is not
> allowed. For this reason, the form 100m might be preferred.
>
> CPU is always requested as an absolute quantity, never as a relative
> quantity; 0.1 is the same amount of CPU on a single-core, dual-core,
> or 48-core machine.

**Meaning of memory and allowed values:**

> Limits and requests for memory are measured in bytes. You can express
> memory as a plain integer or as a fixed-point number using one of
> these suffixes: E, P, T, G, M, K. You can also use the power-of-two
> equivalents: Ei, Pi, Ti, Gi, Mi, Ki. For example, the following
> represent roughly the same values: `128974848, 129e6, 129M, 123Mi`

Answer (score 1):

It's documented in situ in each subsystem but under the hood both of those are the same thing, a struct called a Quantity. Check out https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/api/resource#Quantity for the exhaustive explanation but basically `200m` == `0.2` and `1Gi` == 2^30 == 1073741824. The actual meanings of those numbers are context specific, but the Quantity parsing is shared.